# How to make VLC always appear centered as opposed to bottom right for large videos?

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player

In Windows, VLC automatically positions low resolution videos in the center of the screen. But it completely hides the bottom of high resolution videos and some of their right side too.

While the top left corner is technically centered, it makes the rest of the video appear bottom right. Can anything be done so the center will show the whole video every time you load a new video in an existing VLC instance?

Please note: the video **does fit** in the screen, and can be moved around manually to the center, so the question is **not** how to make it smaller, just how to center all of it.

[image: VLC appearing as bottom right]

Comment: Windows on most OSes are generated by referencing the top left corner. Any resize is therefore from this corner. You'd need something that can not only resize, but also then measure the window, compare it to your viewport & shift the whole thing over.

Answer (score 0):

`Tools` => `Preferences` => `Show settings` -> `All` => `Interface` -> `Show advanced options` => `Main interfaces` -> `Resize interface to the native video size`

[image]

Comment: See my comment above… That doesn't work here. It resizes from the top left corner, but then if it's too close to the bottom right, it is forced by the OS to not go off-screen, so pulls the window left & up until it all fits on screen. There is no attempt to centre it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Have you tried it ? Have you experienced what it is doing ? After you set up I wrote please resize your VLC and double click on any of your video clips.

Comment: Of course I've tried it. I'd tried it long before your answer, hence my first comment above. tbh I either run it at a pre-determined size [without letting it auto-resize] or fullscreen, these days, just because it's hard to control otherwise.

Comment: I too tried to disable this option before asking this question, but it seems to make no difference.